# Парсинг с сохранением ввода пользователя и соответственного изменения ссылки [TelegramAPI]

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot

Пишу телеграм-бот для транскрипции с английского языка. Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import telebot

url = 'https://wooordhunt.ru/word/'
API_KEY = '' ## токен
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
reqWords = soup.find_all('span', class_='transcription')
    
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите слово:')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

 def tran(message):
    if message.text.lower() in '???':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, reqWords)
        del reqWords
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Не удалось найти транскрипцию этого слова')
    
bot.polling()
```

После каждого ввода пользователем информации мне необходимо изменять ссылку тем, что пользователь ввёл: логично было бы это сделать с помощью `.join(input_string)` или `+`, однако в момент объявления url программа еще не знает про message. Еще мне нужно понять что вставить вместо "???", посколько я пока не знаю как правильно составить if/else конструкцию в данном случае. Буду крайне признателен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def tran(message):
    url = f'https://wooordhunt.ru/word/{message.text.lower()}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    reqWords = soup.find_all('span', class_='transcription')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, reqWords)
```